# get the latest added entry from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to get the latest entry (added_on) from the table where client_id and financial_year are same, but i don't have the client id or even financial year to compare i need to compare them in the table it self.

[image]

i used following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM file_mgmt fm
     , client c
     , cupboard cb 
  where fm.client_id = c.client_id 
   AND fm.cupboard_id = cb.cupboard_id
   AND fm.status = 'Active' 
 GROUP 
    BY fm.client_id
     , fm.financial_year
```

and i got this output, which is unique against each client_id and financial_year but its not the latest entry

[image]

Please help in getting the latest entry.

Comment: you could use LIMIT keyword

Comment: Thank You for your reply guys but by adding limit 1 the output of whole query is getting limited by one, and also i am not getting the desired output....

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help

```
  SELECT * FROM file_mgmt fm, client c, cupboard cb where fm.`client_id` = c.`client_id` AND fm.`cupboard_id` = cb.`cupboard_id` AND fm.status = 'Active' 
    GROUP BY fm.`client_id`, fm.`financial_year`
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: same output as i got, no latest entry

Comment: can you guys please stop and help me

Answer (score 0):

As you are using group by you have to use inner query first then you can use it

```
SELECT fm.*,c.*,cb.* FROM file_mgmt fm, client c, cupboard cb 
JOIN (SELECT file_mgmt_id,client_id, financial_year,max(added_on) 
FROM file_mgmt GROUP BY client_id,financial_year) as fm1 
ON fm.file_mgmt_id = fm1.file_mgmt_id
where fm.`client_id` = c.`client_id` AND 
fm.`cupboard_id` = cb.`cupboard_id` AND fm.status = 'Active'
```

**EDIT**

try this simpler query instead

```
   SELECT fm.*,max(added_on) FROM file_mgmt fm, 
   client c , cupboard cb 
   where fm.client_id = c.client_id 
   AND fm.cupboard_id = cb.cupboard_id
   AND fm.status = 'Active'  
   group by client_id,financial_year ;
```

Comment: Unknown column 'fm.client_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Show your query. My suggestion will not provide this error as it already has table fm which has client_id

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
ORDER BY added_on DESC
LIMIT 1
```

at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM file_mgmt fm
     , client c
     , cupboard cb 
  where fm.client_id = c.client_id 
   AND fm.cupboard_id = cb.cupboard_id
   AND fm.status = 'Active' 
 GROUP 
    BY fm.client_id
     , fm.financial_year
ORDER BY added_on DESC
LIMIT 1
```